# DataType Conversion from string to date & from string to ip in convert processor

Tags: kibana, elastic-stack, filebeat

I want to convert one of the field from string to date format.
and secondly from string to ip datatype using pipeline file created.

I am trying the same with the convert processor available but it will throw error as
"ip is not supported" and date format is not supported I checked the same from the document.

Can someone suggest how to perform this task.

I want my date & IP field convertible to their respective datatype and the mappings should be visible

I have tried with 
convert:{ field:response_date
          type: auto
}

Tried with auto as from the document it was mentioned that it will convert the field nearly to a matching datatype.
 This also didn't worked.

Can anyone suggest what do to in this case.